# Proto theme google map issue with DNN application

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have implemented the proto theme to my dnn application.

While i have hosted my application to my development server, Google map is working fine.

When I have moved my code to the live server, it stops working.

Getting "missing key map error" error message while checking the console.

Not able to locate

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you need the entire source to the map instead of

```
//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
```

Have you gone back to google maps and tried exporting the code snippet / link again?